# angular-ui-router: how to clear and reconfigure states?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am dynamically loading my states (based on a server call) in `app.run`.
`window.$stateProviderRef` is just a reference to `$stateProvider` set on the window object in `app.config(..)`

```
app.run(function($http) {
    $http.get('/api/states').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            angular.forEach(data, function(state) {
                window.$stateProviderRef.state(state.name, { url: state.url, templateUrl: state.templateUrl) : state.templateUrl });
            });

        });

});
```

Is it possible to somehow clear or reload the state configuration? So that previous states aren't valid and new states loaded?

Comment: I would assume you couldn't unless you wrote the hook. All configuration is done in the provider. This done before the run phase of angular js. The only way you could re configure is to write your own mechanism to get into the configure state... but that seems like going against the grain. We grab states before angular is bootstrapped, then inject them into the config.

Comment: Please explain your use case. I have a hard time understanding why you would need to clear the states... I guess you already have them configured and then you would want to reconfigure them... but why, and what kind of work flow brings you to this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually not possible at this point but is on the Angular Roadmap, you can keep up with the progress here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1095

Comment: That link is additionally interesting in that it includes a clarified use case -  providing different routes to users once they are authenticated and then clearing them upon logging out (or otherwise changing their level of authentication).